# Best method to collect a random sample from a collection of files

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, filesystems, directory

Suppose there is a directory holding 300 data files. I want to randomly select 200 of those files and move them into another directory. Is there a way to do that under Unix/Linux?

Comment: [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) can probably do this in the twinkling of an eye with `list.files()`...

Comment: I'd vaguely plug together `shuf` and `head` (or just use `shuf -n`, should've read the man page...)

Answer (score 36):

If your system has `shuf`, you can use this quite conveniently (even handling ugly file names):

```
shuf -zen200 source/* | xargs -0 mv -t dest
```

If you don't have `shuf` but have a `sort` that takes `-R`, this should work:

```
find source -type f -print0 | sort -Rz | cut -d $'\0' -f-200 | xargs -0 mv -t dest
```

Comment: Ah yes, because where else would one look for shuffling than in a tool for sorting. (At least `shuf` isn't called `tros` because it does the opposite of sorting.)

Comment: There's no such thing as the opposite of sorting (in the same sense as there's no such thing as "no weather"). Random is still sorted, it's just sorted randomly.

Comment: What is the "-zen200"?  That's not in any of the documentation for shuf, or anywhere on the Internet, but your example doesn't work without it.  Quite mystical.

Comment: @SigmaX Indeed, quite zen, isn't it. Hint: it's 3 separate flags.

Answer (score 4):

If this needs to be statistically random, you shouldn't use `RANDOM % ${#keys[@]}`. Consider:

1. `$RANDOM` has 32768 unique values
2. The first selection is 1 out of 300 elements
3. 32768 = 109 * 300 + 68

Thus, when selecting the first item, there's a 110/32768~=0.33569% chance for each of the 68 first elements, and 109/32768~=0.33264% chance for each of the other 232 elements to be selected. Picking is repeated several times with different chances, but biased towards the first elements whenever `32768 % ${#keys[@]} -ne 0`, so the error compounds.

**This should be unbiased**, and works with any filename:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    mv -- "$REPLY" /target/dir
done 9< <(find /source/dir -mindepth 1 -print0 | shuf -n 200 -z)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
files=(*)
for (( i=0; i<200; i++ )); do
    keys=("${!files[@]}")
    rnd=$(( RANDOM % ${#keys[@]} ))
    key=${keys[$rnd]}
    mv "${files[$key]}" "$otherdir"
    unset files[$key]
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's solution works great! Something else I've used a lot because it find it easier to remember off the top of my head is something like:

```
cp `ls | shuf -n 200` destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all filenames into an array named "files" in bash:

```
files=( * )
```

size of array:

```
echo ${#files[@]}
```

define 2/3 of them as sample size:

```
take=$((2*${#files[@]}/3)) 

for i in $(seq 1 $take)
do
    r=$((RANDOM%${#files[@]})) 
    echo ${files[r]}
done
```

This will select duplicates, and **is**<strike>n't</strike> tested with filenames with blanks and such.

The simplest way to avoid duplicates is, to iterate over all files, and pick each one with 2/3 chance, but this will not necessarily lead to 200 files.

This will remove a file if it was chosen from the list and fulfill your requirements:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( * )
# define 2/3 of them as sample size:
take=$((2*${#files[@]}/3)) 

while (( i < $take ))
do
    r=$((RANDOM%${#files[@]})) 
    f=${files[r]}
    if [[ -n $f ]]
    then 
        i=$((i+1))    
        echo ${files[r]}
        unset files[r]    
    fi
done
```

Comment: You might select the same file more than once.

Comment: Very nice shell script.  To get around your problem of not getting 200 files, you probably want to use Reservoir Sampling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling  I'm going to be weak and not include a shell script example of this.

Comment: @glennjackman: I wrote so, yes. Needed some minutes to figure out, how to remove entries from the array.

Comment: Minor caveat: `$RANDOM` can only have values 0 through 32767, so this will not work properly if you have more than 32768 files. Also, fetching is biased towards the first files.

Comment: @l0b0: Requirements where, to pick 200 from 300. If the files aren't in the current directory, but on a file server, it will not work too. Different requirements, different answer.

Answer (score 0):

One liner in bash:

```
ls original_directory/|sort -R|head -number_of_files_to_move|while read file; do cp "new_directory/"$file test; done
```

Comment: Please elaborate; U&L is a knowledge base.