# Selecting a random sample from a directory tree

Tags: shell-script, files, directory

I've got a directory that contains directories that contain directories that contain files.  I'd like to select two files at random from each leaf directory.  I found [this question about selecting from a single directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38335/best-method-to-collect-a-random-sample-from-a-collection-of-files), but running it in each of several hundred directories would be a pain.

Comment: Do you strictly want to enumerate files like `dir/sub1/subsub1/file1`, or can the depth vary from one leaf directory to another?

Comment: Strictly full-depth.  If the leaf directories are anywhere else, it means something in my music collection isn't sorted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a fixed depth of the directory structure (per your description, a directory with subsubdirectories with files), you could do something like:

```
for subsubdir in "$directory"/*/*/
do
    find "$subsubdir" -type f | shuf -n 2
done | shuf
```

The final `| shuf` in the assumption that you want the list to be randomized as a whole, and not sorted by directory. Otherwise just drop it.

If you expect newlines in your filenames, you can switch to zero-terminated list of files.

Comment: Please note that `find "$dir" -type f` will also find files in subdirectories.  Add `-maxdepth 1` to prevent that.

Comment: @lcd047 if there are subdirectories, the result is not what he wanted anyhow. naturally there aren't supposed to be any subdirectories (beyond a fixed depth determined by `*/*/*/`) in this approach.

Comment: edited the answer, maybe this makes the intention clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
find /some/dir -type d -not -empty -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f | shuf -n 2' sh {} \;
```

This isn't necessarily the most *efficient* way of doing it though. :)